# Implementing a search bar?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisearchcontroller

I have a project with a `tableView` created on the storyboard. It's pretty simple and I was following a tutorial to do it, my view controller looks like this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = restaurantDisplayNames[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES
     ];
}
```

So when you tap on a cell it puts a check mark next to it. Now I want people to be able to search for things. Problem is, Apple changed the search bar for iOS 8 and supposedly made it simpler but I can't find any tutorials on the `UISearchController` which replaced the depricated method.

So I **dragged and dropped** a **Search Bar and Search Display Controller** into my view controller and added the `UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>` protocol declarations, but I get a crash:

```
'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Whenever I tap on the search bar.

I also have the method

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{

}
```

But it is empty because I don't know what to put in there. Supposedly it is very easy and only requires a few lines of code to get it up and running, but the one tutorial I found here: http://www.stuartbreckenridge.com/blog/examining-the-new-uisearchcontroller-api now only is in swift but doesn't explain what goes in that method.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Man, some of these things are so ridiculously simple yet you have to dig deep to find answers. You'd think Apple could put some tips in XCode about these things, little warnings or something, but here's how I fixed it:

Apparently you need to add

```
if (!cell){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method so it looks like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = restaurantDisplayNames[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

So it generates the cell if it doesn't exist. Not sure why, but oh well ...